# How to configure Ignite to work as a full distributed database?

Tags: distributed, ignite

I'm trying to manage a decentralized DB around a huge number of partial DB instances. Each instance has a **subset** of the whole data and they are all nodes and clients, thus asking for some data the query must be spread to every (group) instance and which one have it will return the data.

Due to avoid lost of data if one instance goes down, I figured out they must replicate its contents with some others. How this scenario can be configured with Ignite?

Supose I have a table with the name and last access datetime of users in a distributed application, like ...

```
class UserLogOns
{
    string UserName;
    DateTime LastAccess;
}
```

Now when the program starts I prepare Ingite for work as a decentralizad DB ...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        TcpCommunicationSpi commSpi = new TcpCommunicationSpi();
        // Override local port.
        commSpi.LocalPort = 44444;
        commSpi.LocalPortRange = 0;

        IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
        // Override default communication SPI.
        cfg.CommunicationSpi = commSpi;

        using (var ignite = Ignition.Start(cfg))
        {                

            var cfgCache = new CacheConfiguration("mio");                
            cfgCache.AtomicityMode = CacheAtomicityMode.Transactional;             
            var cache = ignite.GetOrCreateCache<string, UserLogOns>(cfgCache);

            cache.Put(Environment.MachineName, new UserLogOns { UserName = Environment.MachineName, LastAccess = DateTime.UtcNow });

        }                     

    }
```

And now ... I want to get LastAccess of other "computerB" when ever it was ..

Is this correct? How can it be implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the exact use-case that you want to implement. In general, Ignite provides out of the box everything that you mentioned here.

This is a good way to start with using SQL in Ignite: https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs

Create table with "template=partitioned" instead of "replicated" as it is shown in the example here: https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/getting-started#section-creating-tables, configure number of backups and select a field to be affinity key (a field that is used to map specific entries to cluster node) and just run some queries.

Also check out the concept of baseline topology if you are going to use native persistence: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/baseline-topology.

In-memory mode will trigger rebalance between nodes on each server topology change (node that can store data in/out) automatically.

Comment: This is not providing me anything about "how" only what. Imaging I have a table (distributed decentralized) only with the name of each user logged. How can I do it in c#?

Comment: Based on your description, key-value APIs will be enough for you. Start your Ignite cluster and access the data with key-value calls. This doc page goes with samples for .NET (just swap GridGain with Ignite): https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/key-value-api/basic-cache-operations

Comment: @dmagda why did you say "key-value APIs will be enough for you"? Please can you post a code example to implement it?

Comment: Check this quick start guide by GridGain that can be applied to Ignite, the page includes references to examples (or just find similar examples in Ignite repo): https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/getting-started/quick-start/dotnet